# CSS 2 columns layout with floating from top to bottom

Tags: css, html, css-float, inline

I try to realise a design with two columns which are filled with several div of a different height from top to bottom with an 'overflow' from left to right so that the 2 columns have nearly the same height.

Example:

```
AAA  CCC
AAA  CCC
AAA  
AAA  DDD
     DDD
BBB  
BBB  EEE
BBB
```

But I have no idea to make it happen. I tried something like

```
<div class="items">
   <div class="item even">A</div>
   <div class="item odd">B</div>
   <div class="item even">C</div>
   <div class="item odd">D</div>
   <div class="item even">E</div>
</div>
```

and

```
.item.even { float: left; }
.item.odd { float: right; }
```

or

```
.item { display: inline; }
```

or

```
.item { display: inline-block; }
```

but because of the unknown height and number of the items-div, I have not found an acceptable result. Any ideas? Every hint is appreciated.

Here is an example jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6W96c/

Comment: wrap each column in its own individual div and float them

Comment: @albert: Thanks. I thought about that as well, but I have no control over the creation of the html.

Comment: Of course, I could strip it out with regex, calculate the length of the div add them up and put a closinging and opening div in between. Not very elegant, but that could work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it by inserting a closing and opening div with a regex. Here is the php code:

```
// $html is containing the html code
preg_match_all('#<div class="item .+?</div>#ism', $html, $matches);
$matches = $matches[0];
// Get all the lengths
$totalLength = 0;
$lengths = array();
foreach( $matches as $key=>$match )
{
   $totalLength += strlen($match);
   $lengths[$key] = $totalLength;
}
// Find the div, which is the closest to the middle
$key = 0;
$distanceFromMiddle = $middle = $totalLength / 2;
while( $distanceFromMiddle > abs($lengths[$key] - $middle) )
{
   $distanceFromMiddle = abs($lengths[$key++] - $middle);
}
// Add div in front off the next div
$replace = '</div><div class="items">'.$matches[$key + 1];
$html = str_replace($matches[$key], $replace, $html);
```

Not very elegant, but it works. I am still open to other suggestions. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try something like....

```
.items .even { float: left; clear:both;}

.items .odd { float:right; }
```

It's hard to test your requirements without some HTML.  Maybe you could create a jsFiddle.

Comment: I've just created the jsfiddle and tried your idea. Unfortunately it works also not the way as I expect it to do. Thanks, so far!